# custom css not watching properly in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I would like to understand how Grunt compiles sources in Magento 2.

I have installed Grunt on my server and set my Magento 2 project (add Gruntfile.js and update dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js to add my theme)

I have custom css in app/design/frontend///web/css/custom.css

Comment: "not watching properly" is not a problem description. What is your specific problem? How does that relate to the rest of the statements in your post? What did you try, what did you want to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: Show themes.js if you can